# Which part of the R `scan` function allows for data input?

Tags: r, function

I've typed `> scan` to see the body of the `scan()` function, but I can't figure out which part of it could be responsible for possibility of data input by user.

(If we call function by `x=scan()` we can create `x`, to end interaction press enter when being in empty line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit here:

```
.Internal(scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, 
        na.strings, flush, fill, strip.white, quiet, blank.lines.skip, 
        multi.line, comment.char, allowEscapes, encoding))
```

It's the last bit of code before the function returns. This is a call to `.Internal`, some C code that does the scan.

From `?.Internal`:

```
.Internal performs a call to an internal code which is built in 
to the R interpreter.
```

Comment: How to create such functionality in R without using C ?

Comment: @Qbik You can use `tcl/tk` or any of the widgets packages. I like using the package `gWidgets`, [available from CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I was thinking about console management using base functions - only for teaching myself something new.

Comment: What functionality are you trying to create?